# Using dictionaries instead of switch statements

Tags: c#, dictionary, switch-statement

I am writing a library and a question arose about static classes and static fields/props.
what Im doing:

```
static class PacketFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, Type> RadiusPacketTypes;
    static PacketFactory()
    {
        RadiusPacketTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>() {
            {1,typeof(AuthPacket)},
            {2,typeof(AuthPacket)},
            {3,typeof(AuthPacket)},
            {4,typeof(AccPacket)},
            {5,typeof(AccPacket)},
            {11,typeof(AuthPacket)},
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the PacketBuilder class, that can be used to build a IRadiusPacket object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCodeException"></exception>
    public static PacketBuilder GetInstance(byte code)
    {
        var valueFound = RadiusPacketTypes.TryGetValue(code, out var type);

        if (!valueFound) {
            throw new InvalidCodeException();
        }

        var instance = (IRadiusPacket)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        instance.Code = (Enums.PacketCode)code;
        var packetBuilder = new PacketBuilder(instance);

        return packetBuilder;
    }
}
```

First off, is having a static field considered bad design?
Secondly, basically I made a factory that return an IRadiusPacket, the specific implementation that gets returned depends upon the code. I used a dictionary for this, does this make sense? What would be a better way to solve this? What is another good way to avoid switch statements, that would make sense in this situation.

btw, suggestions and criticisms are always welcome!

Comment: I would say, a private static field to hold constant is ok. But why not using a switch statement? I am not sure, but I think it is better for performance than creating instances by Activator.

Comment: I have done similar things often and like it. The bottom line is: One has to write down the relation between code and type *somewhere*: In code (switch, if-else) or in data (dictionary, array). I generally prefer establishing the relationship in data because it is easier to maintain and can be used in different places without redundancies. The only disadvantage is that the code becomes more abstract (and therefore somewhat harder to understand because the needed information is distributed)  and harder to debug (it is easy to have a breakpoint in a specific els-if branch).

Comment: One thing to consider is that if you know that your key integers (the "code") are always small, you can put the data in an array, indexed with the code, which makes obtaining the type faster. Use a default value of null for the gaps in the array. The static initialization becomes (perhaps, a bit) longer, but it its only performed once. (For a factory it probably has a negligible benefit because the allocation dominates the run time, but in other cases it may be worth it.)